# How to configure HA rootdir for hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, high-availability

I am learning to use Hbase and was confused about a configuration of hbase.rootdir.

The namenode(active) is on server hd1.
The namenode(standby) is on server hd2.

The question is:
    Shall I must configure hbase.rootdir=hd1:9000 ? If the answer is yes, is that means namenode HA id not available for Hbase?

Answer (score 0):

Now I find the answer. 
I can configure the param fs.defaultFS from core-site.xml (in which means the cluster server address) instead of on node address like hd1:9000
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djc5z.png)